# Change image_tag file-name with Javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I always end up writing sth like this in my code:

```
function setSomeImage(image_name) {
$("#some_div").html("<%= image_tag ('image.png') %>");
}
```

I am setting images based on a variable that I pass and I have to use the `image_tag` helper to write it properly in rails. However, Javascript and the `image_tag` don't work together very well.

What I want to do is, I want to manipulate the `image_tag` filename dynamically with javascript.

I can now write sth like this:

```
function setSomeImage(image_name) {
$("#some_div").html('<img src="/assets/'+image_name+'.png">');
}
```

but that is not clean.
I want to use the image_tag helper, sth like this:

```
function setSomeImage(image_name) {
$("#some_div").html('<%= image_tag ('+image_name+') %>');
}
```

but that's not working.
Any idea how I could combine both? Is there any best practice doing this?

Another idea is to pass the `image_path` directly as a variable to the function but that is not always possible.

Answer (score 3):

If your js file has extension of `js.erb`, you'll be able to use [`asset_path helper to display some asset`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb) but ***you won't be able to pass a js variable to it because first ruby part will be evaluated and during that time image_name, a js variable won't be present.***

Answer (score 0):

`image_tag` is rendered by the rails application on the server so it is not possible to use it in JavaScript. The second code block that you thought was not clean is likely as good as you're going to get if you are trying to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: so you mean image_tag and other helpers used in a view are on the server? :)

Comment: That's what I'm saying :)

Comment: and js is not present on the server? It gets injected by browser?

Comment: checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb

Comment: Think of JS as completely different than what rails is doing. JS is only rendered in the browser. The ERB `<%= image_tag ('+image_name+') %>` is only something that rails is going to render in the HTML. The HTML that rails renders can be later manipulated by JavaScript, but you can not use rails view helpers in JavaScript.

Comment: when you use extensions like `.js.erb`, it first evaluates the rails part and then the js part. In previous comment I posted a link, do check it out, btw asset_path is also a rails helper :)

Comment: Rails does not evaluate the js part. The browser evaluates the JS so `image_tag` is not something that JS can comprehend unless you write an image_tag function in JS.

Comment: I didn't say rails is evaluating js part, I'm saying if you'll have a `js.erb` extension then first ruby part will get evaluate by the server and then the js part by some browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81603/discussion-between-sean-mccleary-and-mandeep).

Comment: Sorry can't come on chat right now. Do try that asset_path helper, you'll get to know if it works or not :)